# Log a message from Windows to a Syslog server (Wireguard)

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, wireguard

I would like to know when a Wireguard client set a tunnel up. So is it possible to do something like :

```
PostUp=command_which_creates_a_syslog_event
```

Because I don't see any other way to log when a client set his tunnel up.

Comment: Try to run something like neolog (https://github.com/Neo23x0/neolog) or even just netcat (https://gist.github.com/dwallraff/82a629a5836947ab975a4999ee6b964f).

Comment: @Vadim thanks ! It was what i was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Try to run something like neolog (github.com/Neo23x0/neolog) or even just netcat (gist.github.com/dwallraff/82a629a5836947ab975a4999ee6b964f).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/437009)

Comment: @Thomas, have you read those comments below the post? It looks like the author doesn't agree with you and considers this an answer.

Comment: @Vadim, still just providing two links (in fact two texts being links in theory) is not considered a valid answer here for multiple reasons. It does not explain how to use what is being those links, and those links can become stale at any time. Both reasons why that can not contribute to build a high level long lasting QA forum, which is the aim here.

Comment: It is much better to give a brief and useful answer than no answer at all. It is definitely wrong "high level long lasting qa forum" if it prefers compliance with rules instead of real help. Go and give your perfect answer if you can instead of grumbling.